# How do I configure logrotate for a file in Ubuntu to rotate it as soon as it's size reaches 1KB?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, logging, logrotate

I see an option in logrotate.conf which can specify a size for a file for rotation. However it seems like it runs the cron job (hourly/weekly etc.) and only if the size is greater than the threshold specified in the conf file, does it rotate the file. My requirement is for the rotation to happen as soon as the file reaches the threshold and not be bound by time at all. Is there a way to achieve this using logrotate ?

Comment: Instead of `cron`, use `inotifywait`, to get a trigger, when the file gets updated. I am assuming that the updates are not frequent, but are bulk.

Comment: If we are talking about a log file that is written several times by second, verify its size on each write action could produce an overload.